# accessing a webpage stored on a home server

Tags: linux, apache, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running a raspberry pi using raspbian linux. I have apache web service installed and when i type in my ip address into the address bar of a browser it loads the default apache webpage saying it all works.

I have another folder located in home/Client5 on this device from which i am trying to load an index.html page but i am recieving a 404 not found error. eg

192.304.0.22/home/Client5/index.html

```
Not Found

The requested URL /home/Client5/task5.html was not found on this server.
```

I gather that theres something wrong in the above web adress or is it that i have to place this folder within the apache folder?

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions.

1/ If you want to keep the default apache pages, add a virtualhost (there are tons of docs on this, I don't think it needs to be repeated here).

2/ If you don't care about the default apache pages, edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and change `DocumentRoot` to make it point to `/home/Client5/` . Add an `index.html` file in there, hit the Raspberry IP in your browser, you should see your page.

You might need to `chmod -R ugo+rwX /home/Client5`.

I don't know what you have under `/home/Client5`, but if it's a regular user, this setup is highly insecure. There are a bunch of additional steps to take if you want to host under home directories (first step, don't put pages in $HOME but create a subdir). It is safer to have a dedicated place with proper perms outside home dirs unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: What if He want to add client6, client7 etc. ?
I prefer learn how to make good Virtual Hosts, It will be very useful :) (sorry for grammar)

Comment: The question was about one directory ("I have another folder") in /home/Client5, not about /home/ClientX with X varying from 0 to n.

Comment: True, but 'client5' is delusory :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it working in local ? (XXX.XXX.X.XX:80) ? Surely yes, so take a look at your router.

Comment: just using the the ip address alone works however i would like to access the index.html which is in home/Client5/index

Comment: @jakon : or change your root directory from /var/www to /custom/path

Comment: ok user3187726, I've misunderstood because I've seen 2 ip address in your post.. now there is one but surely it was edited like mine, with just XXX now oO
all those edits are making me paranoiac xD

Comment: Hahaha I can't comment on any post except my owns (please give me some points x'), anyway @leucos : well done

Comment: @jakon : IMO you can still create vhost after the root dir is changed (thus because each vhost has its own DocRoot) and even if you need many sites that are in the same directory tree it seems to me that you could use the location apache directive too. Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have apache2, you local ip indicate to folder '/var/www/'.
If you want host page in '/home/Client5' you have to make virtual host :)

@edit
Read about it [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/)